# how to go to next activity after purchasing the button?

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase, onclicklistener

how to intent to the SecondActivity after purchasing the button? I did the purchasing but it just stays in the firstActivity

```
    Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    if (Button1 !=null)
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(first.this, SKU_PREMIUM, 1372, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
                Intent intent=new Intent(first.this, second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```

how to do it?

help please

Comment: Show us the log with the error. Also, you should indent your code right after the if statement, just for readability.

Comment: Did you try to do it as it stands in documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html 
I mean declaring `mPurchaseFinishedListener` with method `onIabPurchaseFinished` implemented ? If so, please give us all code and error logs.

Comment: it just work well with no error but doesn't go to the secondactivity

and here's some of the log

 ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0

 ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1

{com.application.kaml.shaheen/com.application.kaml.shaheen.first}} show : true

 #3 mView = null

 D/LOG: onActivityResult(1372,-1,Intent { (has extras) }

 D/LOG: onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.

I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@67d4442 time:252726536

Comment: @GrzegorzKrauze yeah didnt work